# DataGrid Setting the size of columns in code behind when the columns are auto generated

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am auto generating my columns

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid1"   ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

Now I want to set the size of each column in the code behind , to do something like this

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I just want to attach to each column "Auto" , and to the last "*" , and everything in code behind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this

```
int lastColumn= dataGrid.Columns.Count -1;
dataGrid.Columns[lastColumn].Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

for(int i = 0 ; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count -1; i ++)
    dataGrid.Columns[i].Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
```

As you are `AutoGeneratingColumns` you can handle the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event of dataGrid and put code above inside that event

Comment: I have tried to put this code in the xaml.cs file but I am getting dataGrid.Columns.Count to be zero . I think It's because I am using mvvm pattern. Any Idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Which event are you subscribing to? See my edit. Handle the event which will be triggered when auto generation of column is done. In that way you will not find count = 0

Comment: You want to be listening to the datagrid's AutoGeneratedColumns event.

Comment: `UIElement.Measure(availableSize) cannot be called with NaN size.` Your solution is producing this error.

Comment: I had the same problem as rapsalands but was able to fix it by changing the value in the DataGridLength constructor from 0 to 1.