# Need to Set Row and column width and height in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have one scenarion in which i need to set my rows and columns width with out horizontal and vertical scroll.I have a fixed grid of 75 Columns and 41 Rows, it binds with simple for loop and its autogeneratecolumns is True. How i can set my rows and columns dimension as per my screen.

Images of Screen i got.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I do not want any scroll and want that my 41 rows and 75 columns fit inside the one screen.

My Code (xaml.cs):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
{
DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
col.ColumnName = i.ToString();
dt.Columns.Add(col);
}
for (int i = 1; i <= 41; i++)
{
DataRow _r = dt.NewRow();
for (int j = 1; j <= 75; j++)
{
_r[j.ToString()] = j.ToString();
}
dt.Rows.Add(_r);
}
grdRowsColumns.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

How to set its rows and columns width to mininum so that it can adjust with in a space with out scroll.

Xaml File:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdRowsColumns" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,-9,10,79">
</DataGrid>
```

In Xaml i have only DataGrid without any column.

Please suggest how i can do that thing.

Answer (score 4):

I found something that might guide you in the right direction!

[Customized auto-generated columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

refers to how you can "Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control"

furthermore this link: [datagrid-setting-the-size-of-columns-in-code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881684/datagrid-setting-the-size-of-columns-in-code-behind-when-the-columns-are-auto-ge)

Hope this helps you.

**Update**:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272071/setting-max-autogenerate-width-on-autogenerated-columns-in-a-datagrid) is another suggestion on how you could do this.

**Update**
in xaml you can also write:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*"  />
```

this will set all your columns to the width of your screen/parent control.

however havn't figured out how to manipulate "RowHeight" in xaml without setting a template/style

Answer (score 2):

simple as that

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" >
   <DataGrid Name="grdRowsColumns" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,-9,10,79"/>
</Viewbox>
```